# Problem Footer have shadow when insert others content

Tags: html, css

hay can u help me to find a solution after many days I try this coding footer. when I insert a new design as my content, when I scroll up, the footer shows the shadow between my content. i try many time with different coding but not working, i just want to make sure my footer not stay static at the bottom. i just want to fix what the problem with the shadow between footer and my design

```css
.section{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.testimonial{
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial:hover{
   transform: translateY(-20px);
   box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

.testimonial .card{

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: gold;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial .card .layer{

    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 99.5%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(228, 59, 87), gold);
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial .card:hover .layer{
    left: 0;

}
 
.testimonial .card .content{
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}   

.testimonial .card .content p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #000;
} 

.testimonial .card .content .image{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: .5s;

}

.testimonial .card .content .details h2{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial .card:hover .content .details h2{
    color: white;
}

.testimonial .card .content .details span{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    transition: .5s;

}

.testimonial .card:hover .content .details span{
 color: white;
 position: relative;

}
```

```html
<style>
 .footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
   text-align: center;
   transition: none;
}
</style>


<section style="margin-left: 80px;">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her 
                    little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee 
                    shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know 
                    the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. 
                    Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has 
                    a different kind of feel.”</p>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img width="100px" src="img/sarah2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2>Artist<br><span>Vip Customer</span></h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her 
                    little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee 
                    shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know 
                    the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. 
                    Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has 
                    a different kind of feel.”</p>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img width="100px" src="img/susan.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2>Public<br><span>Regular Customer</span></h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her 
                    little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee 
                    shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know 
                    the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. 
                    Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has 
                    a different kind of feel.”</p>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img width="100px" src="img/erika.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2>Public<br><span>Customer</span></h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<div class="footer">
    <p>  Copyright &COPY; 2020 | SENERITY CALLS BEAUTY SPA.CO</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove `position: fixed` from `.footer` class. This is what causing the footer to stick to the bottom of your document.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.testimonial{
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial:hover{
   transform: translateY(-20px);
   box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

.testimonial .card{

    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: gold;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial .card .layer{

    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 99.5%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(228, 59, 87), gold);
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial .card:hover .layer{
    left: 0;

}
 
.testimonial .card .content{
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}   

.testimonial .card .content p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #000;
} 

.testimonial .card .content .image{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: .5s;

}

.testimonial .card .content .details h2{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial .card:hover .content .details h2{
    color: white;
}

.testimonial .card .content .details span{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    transition: .5s;

}

.testimonial .card:hover .content .details span{
 color: white;
 position: relative;

}

 .footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
   color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
   text-align: center;
   transition: none;
   z-index:99;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<section style="margin-left: 80px;">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her 
                    little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee 
                    shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know 
                    the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. 
                    Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has 
                    a different kind of feel.”</p>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img width="100px" src="img/sarah2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2>Artist<br><span>Vip Customer</span></h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her 
                    little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee 
                    shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know 
                    the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. 
                    Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has 
                    a different kind of feel.”</p>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img width="100px" src="img/susan.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2>Public<br><span>Regular Customer</span></h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>“My friend, Elizabeth Shealy, owns this one room spa and I left her 
                    little oasis just this morning. If you have ever spotted a coffee 
                    shop off the beaten track or a cafe in an unexpected area, you know 
                    the feeling of finding a gem that perhaps no one else in the city knows about. 
                    Elizabeth’s nook is that sort of find. Its as if you’re in another part of the world-it has 
                    a different kind of feel.”</p>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img width="100px" src="img/erika.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2>Public<br><span>Customer</span></h2>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="footer">
    <p>  Copyright &COPY; 2020 | SENERITY CALLS BEAUTY SPA.CO</p>
  </div>
```